# AJAX y tablas con funciones

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, dom, html-tabla

Holaamigos, tengo un problemita para hacer el codigo que me arroje la correcta informacion que busco para mi WEB. Pero se los platico :
Tengo un archivo xml que va mas o menos asi:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='archivo.xsl' ?>

<bodega>
<inventario>
<Descripcion>Comida de tortuga</Descripcion>
<Codigo>0010</Codigo>
<Clasif>11 200</Clasif>
<precio>1200</precio>
</inventario>

<inventario>
<Descripcion>Comida de gato</Descripcion>
<Codigo>0080</Codigo>
<Clasif>12 700</Clasif>
<precio>1200</precio>
</inventario>

<inventario>
<Descripcion>Collar de perro</Descripcion>
<Codigo>0120</Codigo>
<Clasif>14 111</Clasif>
<precio>1200</precio>
</inventario>
</bodega>
```

El cual llamo desde un boton predefinido con el siguiente script:

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "archivo.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Descripcion</th><th>Codigo</th>                                            
  <th>Precio</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("inventario");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("Descripcion")   
[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("Codigo")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue  
+
    "</td><td>"+
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("precio")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue  
+
    "</td></tr>";

}
  document.getElementById("tabla1").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>
```

Esto me da dentro de una tabla con id "tabla1" todos los datos de mi xml, pero como se darán cuenta este archivo es solo un ejemplo, en el real tengo cientos de artículos que busco enlazar con una condición que muestre solo los artículos con cierta clasificación.
Para crear un botón con llamado de función para cada una de las clasificaciones y así llamar solo ciertos artículos y no todo el archivo.

Trate de con un while(), de varias formas pero sin exito, busco que las etiquetas "inventario" que contengan la "Clasif" con el valor numerico  14 111 sean mostradas unicamente ignorando al resto para dar en display.
 XP

Alguna idea? Saludos y mil gracias 
Aguante Latinos!

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente se utiliza XSLT para transformar XML a HTML, puedes encontrar un ejemplo de como hacerlo con Javascript en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943050/xslt-and-xml-content-not-loading-in-microsft-edge-and-internet-explorer-browsers/38956738#38956738 y luego puedes utilizar el programa de XSLT (`archivo.xsl`)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- para el parametero "clasificacion" puedes pasar '' para seleccionaor todas las 
         clasificaciones o una simple clasificacion como '11 200' 
         o una lista de clasificaciones separadas por '|', es decir, por ejemplo '11 200|12 700'
    -->
    <xsl:param name="clasificacion" select="''"/>

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="bodega">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Código</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="inventario[$clasificacion = '' or contains(concat('|', $clasificacion, '|'), Clasif)]"/>
            </tbody>
        </table>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="inventario">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Descripcion | Codigo | precio"/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="inventario/*">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

En tu HTML utilizas el Javascript

```
<script src="https://www.promisejs.org/polyfills/promise-7.0.4.min.js"></script>
```

y

```
  function transform(xmlUrl, xslUrl, xsltParams, targetElement) {
    Promise.all([loadDoc(xmlUrl), loadDoc(xslUrl)]).then(function(data) {
      var xmlDoc = data[0];
      var xslDoc = data[1];

      if (typeof XSLTProcessor !== 'undefined') {
        var proc = new XSLTProcessor();
        proc.importStylesheet(xslDoc);

        for (var prop in xsltParams) {
          proc.setParameter(null, prop, xsltParams[prop]);
        }

        var resultFrag = proc.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, targetElement.ownerDocument);

        targetElement.textContent = '';
        targetElement.appendChild(resultFrag);
      }
      else {
          var template = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XslTemplate.6.0');
          template.stylesheet = xslDoc;
          var proc = template.createProcessor();

          for (var prop in xsltParams) {
            proc.addParameter(prop, xsltParams[prop]);
          }

          proc.input = xmlDoc;

          proc.transform();

          var resultHTML = proc.output;

          targetElement.innerHTML = resultHTML;
      }
    });
  }
```

entonces puedes utilizar por ejemplo un botón

```
<input type="button" value="clasificación 11 200"
  onclick="transformar('archivo.xml', 'archivo.xsl', { clasificacion : '11 200' }, document.getElementById('resultado'));">
```

y

```
<div id="resultado"></div>
```